# WP8 LongListSelector scrollTo() and Grouping enabled

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm using a `LongListSelector` to display a conversation view. The messages are being separated by date, I'm not using JumpLists.

`MessageCollection` is an `ObservableCollection`, which contains Items of type `MessageCollectionDay`. 
Each `MessageCollectionDay` contains Items of type `Message`.

The complete `MessageCollection` is bound to the `LongListSelector`.

Each new item is manually added to its according `ObservableCollectionDay`.

Now I want the `LongListSelector` to scroll down to the latest added item.

I tried

```
list.UpdateLayout();
list.ScrollTo(list.ItemsSource[list.ItemsSource.Count - 1]);
```

but it just jumps to the top of the last group, not to the last item.

Any way to jump to the last item in the grouped list?

Comment: The behavior is correct, it scrolls down to the last list element. Unfortunately, the last element is a group of items which themselves are not part of the main list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a small (height = 1), invisible (opacity = 0), empty group to the end of the list and scroll to that.

Comment: I added an empty group on the last position and enabled HideEmptyGroups in the List Properties -> perfect!